# Running code from Jupyter-Notebook fails but runs with no problems in Terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've hit a snag using Jupyter notebook in Anaconda on a Mac. My setup is:

```
MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 (default shell zsh)
Anaconda-Navigator 1.9.12
Jupyter-client 5.3.4
Jupyter-console 6.1.0
Jupyter-core 4..1
```

Basically, I have some Python code to extract some text from an old Word document. The code uses the textract library (https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Unfortunaltey, this library is not included in Anaconda and it has some other dependencies, most notably in this case a library called antiword.

The steps I've taken so far:

1. Installed Mac Ports and used it to install several packages (e.g. poppler, antiword, unrtf, tesseract, swig). Installation appeared to be successful. The directories /opt/local and /opt/local/bin (which is where the above binaries are located) were added to $PATH with no problems.
2. Created an environment (myenv) in Anaconda using Python 3.8. Added various libraries including jupyter.
3. Opened a Terminal with myenv activated. Installed textract using:

   % pip install textract

This all seemed to work fine and there were no error messages.

Now, if I open myenv with Python or with iPython from the Anaconda-Navigator app, a terminal window opens and I can run the following commands:

```
>>> import textract
>>> myText = textract.process('path-to-doc-file')
>>> print(myText)
```

The output from the last command, as expected, is all the text contained in the Word document. This supports the idea that all the necessary libraries and dependencies have been installed correctly.

If I open myenv environment using Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda-Navigator app, a web page appears and I can create a new notebook. However, if I try to run exactly the same commands in a cell of the notebook, I get the following errors:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'antiword'

The command `antiword path-to-file.doc` failed because the executable `antiword` is not installed on your system. Please make sure the appropriate dependencies are installed before using textract
```

I was surprised because I thought the Python used in the Terminal and in the Jupyter Notebook were essentially the same. And yet, that doesn't seem to be the case in this situation.

Am I missing a crucial setup step?

Comment: may you check python version , that is being used by jupyter. In my case both were different, so i installed the module for both pip  to work on terminal as well as jupyter.

Comment: I've tried creating other environments in Anaconda using Python 3.7 (v3.8 used in original). However, same problem still exists. Interestingly, as a work-around, I was able to create a virtual environment using a stand-alone version of Python 3.7 (downloaded from python.org) and pip installed jupyter and textract in activated venv. In this setup, the jupyter notebook and text extract seems to work with no issues.

Comment: I experienced the same problem. The miniconda installation i was using seems not able to read the shell executables that are installed in the host system. Calling antiword using os.popen() works. My guess is that the $PATH is not set correctly in the virtual environment. However, i don't know how to change it.